# What are all the wasm* files being listed in the Script Documents folder at runtime?

Tags: blazor

At runtime I get a metric ton of these showing in visual studio, under the "Script Documents" folder.  Any idea what this content is?
[image]

Comment: Looks like Web Assembly. https://webassembly.org/

Comment: Yes, but why so many of them and what are they?

Comment: Is it newest Blazor 0.7.0? Which operating system are you using, windows?

Comment: Yes, 0.7 and Windows 10 pro